# Python Flask: How to convert a query object to string?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

This issue has confused me for a long time and I searched for a few days but still cannot get it resolved, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732871/flask-sqlalchemy-exc-interfaceerror-app-models-menu-object-at-0x7f287026dd10), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888698/sqlalchemy-exc-interfaceerror-unprintable-interfaceerror-object), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398856/how-to-convert-python-object-into-string).

Below code returns a query object and it shows correctly in the select field.
But when submitting to database, the errors occurred.

```
  # Query the user with Role.id == 4 as reviewer
  def reviewer_choices():
      return User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.id == 4)

  # Build a select field
  class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
   form_extra_fields = {
    'reviewer': sqla.fields.QuerySelectField(
    query_factory=reviewer_choices,
  )}
```

I tried to define  `__repr__` and `__str__` in order to convert it to string but in vain, is there any other way to convert the query object to string? Thanks in advance.

**1. __repr__**:
      The error returns:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   InterfaceError:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   # ...
   # ...
   def __repr__(self):
     return self.first_name
```

**2. __str__**:
      The error returns:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError InterfaceError: (raised as a result of
>   Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block
>   if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error
>   binding parameter 8 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'INSERT INTO
>   project

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   # ...
   # ...
   def __str__(self):
     return self.first_name
```

I currently used:

**In the Project class**

```
class Project(db.Model):
   # ...
   reviewer = db.Column(db.Unicode(128)) 
   # ...
```

**In the Project table**

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
   # ...
   `reviewer1`  TEXT,
   # ...
```

Comment: Can you show your Project model definition.

Comment: @pjcunningham: Kindly see the updated post ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that having `reviewer` as string field in your Project model is intentional (as opposed to being a relationship).

A `QuerySelectField` data property stores an ORM instance, which in your case is an instance of a `User` model, whilst your `reviewer` field is a string, hence the error message.

You can create an inherited `QuerySelectField` class and override its `populate_obj` method to convert the selected User instance to a string of your choice, e.g.

```
class ProjectQuerySelectField(QuerySelectField):

    def populate_obj(self, obj, name):
        # obj is the current model being edited/created
        # name is the field name - 'reviewer' in this instance
        # self.data is the user instance selected in the form
        setattr(obj, name, str(self.data))
```

Note the use of the `str` function to get the string representation of the selected user instance.

See self-contained sample app below. Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/project/ to see how a selected user gets converted to a string.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.fields import QuerySelectField
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, RoleMixin, UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


from flask_admin import Admin
# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(254), unique=True)

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join(filter(None, [self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email]))


class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    reviewer = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)


class UserView(ModelView):
    column_list = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'roles']
    form_columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'roles']


class RoleView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ['name', 'description']


def reviewer_choices():
    # return User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.id == 4)
    return User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.name == u'Reviewer')


class ProjectQuerySelectField(QuerySelectField):

    def populate_obj(self, obj, name):
        setattr(obj, name, str(self.data))


class ProjectView(ModelView):

    form_extra_fields = {
        'reviewer': ProjectQuerySelectField(
            query_factory=reviewer_choices,
        )}


admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(RoleView(Role, db.session))
admin.add_view(ProjectView(Project, db.session))


def build_sample_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    # Reviewer will have id : 4 and will have index 3 in _roles list
    _roles = []
    for _name in ['Admin', 'Editor', 'Reader', 'Reviewer']:
        _role = Role(name=_name)
        _roles.append(_role)

    db.session.add_all(_roles)

    # get the "Reviewer" Role
    _reviewer_role = _roles[3]

    # Give Paul and Serge "Reviewer" role
    _user_1 = User(first_name="Paul", last_name="Cunningham", email="paul@example.com", roles=[_reviewer_role])
    _user_2 = User(first_name="Luke", last_name="Brown", email="luke@example.com")
    _user_3 = User(first_name="Serge", last_name="Koval", email="serge@example.com", roles=[_reviewer_role])

    db.session.add_all([_user_1, _user_2, _user_3])

    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_sample_db()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: @ pjcunningham: Thanks so much for the reply and your app works well. However, for my app the error occurred: `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
InterfaceError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 8 - probably unsupported type.`  I can see the reviewer correctly showed in the drop down button, but when saving the error occurred.